# sapui5 ui table how to unselect the rows by unchecking the row checkbox

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Im facing a small issue in UI table. How can we remove the selected rows if we unselect the checkbox for a row? To get the row data im using below code and it is working fine without any issues.

[image]

```
getEnterDetailCount:function(oEvent){
            var oRowContext = oEvent.getParameter("rowContext");
            var oContextObject = oRowContext.getObject();
            roomsArray.push(oContextObject);
        };
```

Using the above method, If i select the row im able to get the Complete Row Data.
But if i unselect the row, Still it is considering as a row selection and count is getting increased.

In XML im using **rowSelectionChange** event to check and uncheck the checkbox on the row

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Pavantej

Answer (score 0):

For **sap.m.table** you can use `getSelectedItems` to get all selected rows from your table. Loop all selected rows and put them in your array.

```
getEnterDetailCount:function(oEvent){
  var oContextObject;
  var roomsArray = [];
  var oTable = this.getView().byId("myTable");
  var aSelectedItems = oTable.getSelectedItems();

  aSelectedItems.forEach( function(v,i){
     oContextObject = v.getBindingContext().getObject();
     roomsArray.push(oContextObject);
  });
};
```

For **sap.ui.table** you can use `getSelectedIndices()`

```
getEnterDetailCount:function(oEvent){
  var oContextObject;
  var roomsArray = [];
  var oTable = this.getView().byId("myTable");
  var aSelectedIndices = oTable.getSelectedIndices();

  aSelectedIndices.forEach( function(v,i){ 
     oContextObject = oTable.getContextByIndex(v).getObject();
     roomsArray.push(oContextObject);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But the Solution which you proposed is not working. im getting error like oTable.getSelectedItems() is not a function. Actually im using sap.ui.table, But im not sure how getSelectedItems() will work? i guess that might work for sap.m.table

Comment: Added a function for sap.ui.table to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didnt worked for me. Actually on sap.ui.table if i click on the row checkbox, row data should get added in to the array and if i uncheck the same checkbox the row data should get removed.

Comment: This function creates a new array every time with all selected rows.

Comment: is there any workaround like "new array should not get created every time, addition and deletion of elements should happen in one array"?

Comment: Is there a reason for that? It's way more complicated to add and delete items instead of create a new array.

Comment: If we are creating new array everytime, then we are repeatedly getting the duplicate data when it is running in for loop